# What is the difference between using a Google API Client Library and hitting the token endpoint on your own

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I was following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth). Now I have succesfully sent the id_token to the server endpoint. Now to verify what is the best way of doing that?

Among the 2 ways mentioned, Google api client library and hitting the token endpoint:: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo ,only limitation that I see that hitting the token endpoint has a daily quota. Other than that, both are making network calls to validate the id_tokens.

Then why this statement is mentioned: **Calling this endpoint involves an additional network request**?

Does the api libraries implement some mechanism by which they cache the network call result or else what is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API client library should be caching a cert for future validations and thus improving end user latency and reliability, hence is the recommended approach for high volume services. The token info endpoint is fine for low volume requests or development.